# Why did Vibrator suddenly stop working and how can I fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, vibration

I've been working on an app for Android using Kotlin which is a copy of a simple game and few friends and I created as a .bat a few years ago. I have a vibration function in it just as a small extra feature, but all of a sudden, without restarting or updating Android Studio, or changing any code at all, it stopped working, saying it requires a permission I already added. I can click the quick fix button several times and I'll have several identical permissions in Android Manifest but it still wont work weather there's 1, 2 copies, or none. It started when I created a new activity but I haven't added anything in it yet and I deleted it to see if that would fix it, but it didn't. I tried cleaning the project and restarting Android Studio but nothing will work. I don't know how I can get Vibrator working again. I have the exact same code for the vibrations on several other projects and they all work fine. My code for the vibrations is this:

```
private fun vibrate(time: Long) {

    val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    if (vibrator.hasVibrator()) { // Vibrator availability checking
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(time, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE)) // New vibrate method for API Level 26 or higher
        } else {
            vibrator.vibrate(time) // Vibrate method for below API Level 26
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: After some raging and testing, I have fixed this weird issue, for the most part. the errors will only go away if I suppress them with "@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")" which then allows the app to build and run. The app does properly vibrate just like it did before, though what I'll call ghost errors still come back if I delete the suppressLint. Every one in a while, even the suppressLint fails to suppress it and I have to delete and re-enter that line to fix it again.  I still have no idea what caused this. Ever since Android Studio Chipmunk came out, its been a lot more glitchy. If I could get any information on what might have caused this or how to make it stop, I'd greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE 2: I believe it has something to do with how making a new activity imports AppCompatActivity as "import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity" instead of the usual "import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity"
After re-adding the activity I wanted and making it work, I couldn't get it to build for other reasons, which was mainly the "v7" in the imports. when I changed the import from "androidx.support.v7.app..." to "androidx.appcompat.app..." it now works fine, even without the SuppressLint I had to add previously. I believe this is the cause of my issue but I would like someone to confirm this.

UPDATE 3: I believe the complete fix is to migrate to AndroidX. I dont know why I had to do this as I created the project 1 day ago but it fixed the reoccurring errors and build fails. Just go to refactor in the top of the screen, then click on "Migrate to AndroidX..."

Comment: you "already added" permission (to manifest I'm assuming), but does your app have granted it? (check in system settings of app, introduce runtime-permission flow if needed). also worth checking some "battery optimisation" options on your device (custom per manufacturer), maybe your app is "blacklisted"

Comment: My app vibrates perfectly fine in the most recent version I could build, but once the vibrator stopped working in the code, it wont build, therefore its an issue with the project, and nothing on the device.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a copy-paste from my 3rd update, but this should fix the issue if anyone else has the same issue. I believe the complete fix is to migrate to AndroidX. I dont know why I had to do this as I created the project 1 day ago, but it fixed the reoccurring errors and build fails. Just go to "Refactor" in the top of the screen, then click on "Migrate to AndroidX..."